# A word for "the act of begging"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, verbs, nouns, vocabulary

What is a word for "the act of begging"? For example, the "act of ordaining someone" is called an "Ordination." Likewise, what would one call the "act of begging"?

The sentence I am trying to form:

> This painting captures the penultimate moment of Coriolanus—both the man and the play—in its depiction of the ________ of Veturia and Volumnia.

"Supplication" has a similar meaning, but the connotation is different; supplication is used with regard to a god.

Comment: why can't you use begging, and supplication can be used beyond directed at a god. solicition and entreat also may work

Comment: Is there one besides **begging**?

Comment: Try "Veturia and Volumnia **beseeching** Coriolanus to spare Rome".

Comment: @Kevin you evidently did not understand the question. It's about a painting depicting a crucial moment - not about beggars.

Answer (score 1):

Mendicancy is "the practice of begging." *Merriam-Webster.* So the sentence might be " . . . in its depiction of the mendicancy of Veturia and Volumnia." That seems to parallel ". . . in its depiction of the supplication of Veturia and Volumnia."

Comment: I doubt it: both *begging* and *mendiancy* (note the part of speech as opposed to *mendicancy*) are usually about asking for money, which is out of context here.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, the OED provides the following meaning for *mendicancy* - "The state or condition of being a mendicant or beggar; the habit or practice of begging." A 1987 example quoted is:
*Daily Tel. 7 Jan. 10   The spirit at our universities is one of whining mendicancy and parasitism.* Seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @WS2 exactly - nothing to do with Veturia and Volumnia. Were they in the *habit* of begging? Or was this an extreme one-off unrelated to being a "beggar"?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the precise nature of the begging, there are a number of possible alternatives that sound more impressive.

(from "Synonym discussion of *importune*" section at [M-W.com's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/importune) definition of *importune*; noun forms in [brackets] added by me)

> **beg** [or *begging*] suggests earnestness or insistence in the asking. *⟨They begged for help⟩*
>
> **entreat** [or *entreaty*] implies an effort to persuade or to overcome resistance. *⟨They entreated me to join them⟩*
>
> **beseech** [or *beseeching*] and **implore** [or *imploring*] imply a deeply felt anxiety. *⟨I beseech you to have mercy⟩ ⟨He implored her not to leave him⟩*
>
> **supplicate** [or *supplication*] suggests a posture of humility. *⟨with bowed heads they supplicated their Lord⟩*
>
> **adjure** [or *adjuration*] implies advising as well as pleading. *⟨we were adjured to tell the truth⟩*
>
> **importune** [or *importuning*] suggests an annoying persistence in trying to break down resistance to a request. *⟨importuning viewers for contributions⟩*